# The requested resource is not available in struts2

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, struts, struts-config

I have been developing my first simple  application. I have included all the necessary libraries into the WEB_CONTENT/WEB_INF/lib in order to run a basic struts application. But when i open the url it shows:
   **The requested resource (/StrutsStarter/getStarter.action) is not available**.

I have no idea why it is not working properly because since the dubug gives no error. Any help would be appreciated.

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>StrutsStarter</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>success.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
      "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
      "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
<constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"></constant>
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="getStarter" class="org.aars.action.StarterAction">
        <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>

    </action>

</package>

</struts>
```

**StarterAction**

```
package org.aars.action;

public class StarterAction {

    public String execute(){
        System.out.println("StarterAction Executed");
        return "success";
    }

}
```

**I added these jars**

- commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
- commons-io-2.0.1.jar
- commons-lang-2.4.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
- commons-logging-api-1.1.jar
- freemarker-2.3.19.jar
- javassist-3.11.0.GA.jar
- ognl-3.0.6.jar
- struts2-core-2.3.14.3.jar
- xwork-core-2.3.14.3.jar

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Finally** i found the answer.

I just added one more jar `commons-lang3-3.1.jar` to build path makes it work.

Comment: if that is the problem, you would have got the error stated about missing class in tomcat logs. here after try to look into it if any problem arise in project. good luck

Comment: my gratitude for your valuable and precious guidance